# Decode PHP base64 encode

Tags: php, base64, encode

I have to encode an existing php page to edit it.

Can you help me in it? I'm trying hard to figure it out but it seems it's not so easy as I thought.

Here it is:

```
eval(strrev(";)))ppa_BF_tiBbeW$(31tor_rts(edoced_46esab(lave@"));
```

Comment: `strrev` should give you a hint regarding what's going on here...

Comment: Replace `eval` with `var_dump`, you get `@eval(base64_decode(str_rot13($WebBit_FB_app)));`. This of course has "malicious script" written all over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

executing strrev function we have:
`@eval(base64_decode(str_rot13($WebBit_FB_app)));`

try to print `$WebBit_FB_app` variable, then use `str_rot13()` and `base64_decode()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the base64_decode function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

```
 <?php
     $str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
     echo base64_decode($str);
 ?>
```