# How to encrypt/decrypt uploaded image php/xcode

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode

I've been using this code to upload an image : [how to post an image to the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679009/how-to-post-an-image-to-the-web-server)
and it works fine.

My question is : is there a way to aes-256 encrypt the image with a passphrase before sending it and decrypting it with php on the server? It's like using these functions : [AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone) but instead of NSString, NSData.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/Harinder/1243257

Answer (score 1):

To my idea from **iOS**

you `convert` `image` to `base64` string using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251478/1106035)

Now `encrypt` this `string` int `AES264` using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

**On php side**

`Decrypt` using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628138/how-to-do-aes256-decryption-in-php)

`Decode` `base64` `string` using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922273/decode-php-base64-encode)

Answer (score 0):

http://highaltitudehacks.com/2013/09/26/ios-dev-encrypted-images-and-saving-them-in-app-sandbox/

this is how you achieve image encryption of images in iOS (one way at least) you can then simply post the result. but you have to find a way to exchange your encryption key. It would not be clever to simply send your keys within the same request... and if so you should at least use https

Comment: okay that's on the client side, how would i decrypt it on the server with php ?

Comment: keep in mind that after decrypting you have a binary representation of your image, you can either write it down to a file, or open it with gd, but you should preserve the image type if you don't want to make a  manual detection of it's mime

Comment: i was thinking of doing this : move_uploaded_file(sqAES::decrypt('password',$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']), $uploadfile); wouldn't that solve the problem ?

Comment: this will not work, because you can not move and decrypt the file like this... you should read the file contents, decrypt it and save it to your target location

Comment: so i should do this : $decryptedfile = sqAES::decrypt('password',$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); then this : move_uploaded_file($decryptedfile, $uploadfile); ?

Comment: sorry but i'm very new to encryption and decryption, never used it

Comment: $decryptedfile = sqAES::decrypt('password',file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])); and then file_put_contents($targetfile, $decryptedfile); keep in midn that you have to take the sgAES class from the php.net example to get this to wkr

Comment: it is not a problem that you are new don't worry ;) everyone needs to start somewhere.. the problem is not the encryption itself, it is more the side conditions that can make your life hard :D

Comment: where exactly did you struggle?